# Recursion in C.The program must give the largest element of an array

Tags: c, recursion, void

The program must give the largest element of an array(A) with the help of recursive void TMax.But it's not working.I think that there's an error because of pointers of Max and I can't correct it.Can you help me,please?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void TMax(int A[], int N,int *Max)
{
    if(N==0){
       *Max=A[0];
    }
    else
    {
        *Max=A[N];
         if(A[N]>*Max)
        {
            *Max=A[N];
        }
         TMax(A,N-1,*Max);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int A[] = { 1, 2, 999, 4, 20};
    int N = sizeof(A) / sizeof(A[0]);
    int k=A[N];

   TMax(A,N,&k);

    printf("%d",k);
}
```

Comment: First of all `A[N]` leads to undefined behavior since you are accessing beyond the array `A` limit

Comment: Your compiler must complain (so turn warnings on!): `TMax(A,N-1,*Max);` should be `TMax(A,N-1,Max);` And `int k=A[N];` should be `int k=A[N-1];`

Comment: `int k = A[N]` is array out of range, the acceptable range is **[0 , N-1]**

Comment: Pump up the compiler's warning level, read the warnings issued during compilation, understand them and then fix the code accordingly, do not cast to do so. Do so until no more warnings appear during compilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are passing `int` to `int *` which is wrong and will lead to undefined behavior.

   Even the compiler is warning about the same.

   > ```
   > warning: passing argument 3 of 'TMax' makes pointer from integer wi
   > thout a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   >           TMax(A,N-1,*Max);
   > ```
2. You are accessing the array out of bound, max index is  `N-1`.
3. Your base case is assigning        `*Max=A[0];` in that case your mas will be always zero hence remove the assignment and just return..

Sample code:

```
void TMax(int A[], int N,int *Max)
{
    if(N==0){
       return;
    }
    else
    {
        if(A[N]>*Max)
        {
            *Max=A[N];
        }
         TMax(A,N-1,Max);
    }
}
```

And from `main` you call this way.

```
TMax(A,N-1,&k);
```

Comment: Thank you.Your code is working,now I have another problem)))... when I have a "k" which  is not initilized, it's not working.Is there a way to have a void that will work with not initialized "k"(I mean in the main I have "int k" in place of "int k=A[0]"  .

Comment: You should initialize `k` to `INT_MIN` otherwise your `k` will have junk value.

Answer (score 1):

You have several errors:

in Tmax:

```
    if(N==0){
       *Max=A[0];
    }
```

You want to test whether the array is empty. Then it has *no* elements and even `A[0]` does not exist. Remember that array indexes in C go from `0..n-1`. So also:

```
    *Max=A[N-1];
```

and in `main` too: `int k=A[N-1];`

in Tmax, when you recursively call `Tmax`, you must pass `Max`, as it is already a pointer, and not `*Max`, which would be the *value* of `Max`, so:

```
    TMax(A,N-1,Max);
```

Answer (score 1):

**sizeof(A) / sizeof(A[0])** is going to return you size of array. In your case it is going to return 5 and you are trying to assign **index 5** value of array in **k** but in the case of array index start form **0 to n-1** so k is going to contain garbage value .Try to make proper change in the value of **N**